# Copy lines from two different CSV files matching first element and paste it in 3rd CSV file one after another in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.6

I have two CSV files:

`dump1.csv`:

```
Primary     attribute1    attribute2    attribute3
rowA        3992372839    3778338494    9180339101
rowB        8291392010    3739203044    2840493019
```

`dump2.csv`:

```
Primary     attribute1    attribute2    attribute3
rowA        8911849302    9018383910    8103293202
rowB        7310393021    8301940301    7209301030
```

Now I want to create a third CSV file `dump1_dump2.csv`:

> 1. With  same headers of `dump1.csv` & `dump2.csv`
> 2. Match Rows and copy these one by one in the third file.
> 3. Rename the row names prepending `dump1_` and `dump2_` respectively to distinguish within these.
> 4. After two rows picked up from each dump, third CSV file should put a row there which will give us the `change percentage`.

The third CSV `dump1_dump2.csv` should looks like:

```
Primary     attribute1    attribute2    attribute3
dump1_rowA  3992372839    3778338494    9180339101
dump2_rowA  8911849302    9018383910    8103293202
change %    123.22        138.68        -11.73
dump1_rowB  8291392010    3739203044    2840493019
dump2_rowB  7310393021    8301940301    7209301030
change %    -11.83        122.02        153.80
```

I have written a small snippet:

```
import csv

f1 = open('dump2.csv', 'r')
f2 = open('dump2.csv', 'r')
f3 = open('results.csv', 'w')

c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)

finallist = list(c2)

for hosts_row in c1:
    row = 1
    for final_row in finallist:
        results_row = hosts_row
        if hosts_row[0] == final_row[0]:
            # copy line from dump1.csv, paste it to dump1_dump2.csv and modify hosts_row[0] by appending dump1 & dump2 respectively
            results_row_1 = #new row containing content of dump1
            results_row_2 = #new row containing content of dump2
            break
        row = row + 2
    c3.writerow(results_row_1)
    c3.writerow(results_row_2)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer to your question, you can use pandas for easier and faster evaluation.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("dump1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("dump2.csv")

df1["Primary"] = "dump1_"+df1["Primary"].astype(str)
df2["Primary"] = "dump2_"+df2["Primary"].astype(str)

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index()


df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Primary","attribute1","attribute2","attribute3"])
indx = df3.index.value_counts()
for i, j in indx.iteritems():
    if j == 2:
        tempdf = df3.loc[1].append({"attribute1":((df3.loc[i]["attribute1"].astype(int).diff()/df3.loc[i]["attribute1"].astype(int).values[0])*100).values[1],"attribute2":((df3.loc[i]["attribute2"].astype(int).diff()/df3.loc[i]["attribute2"].astype(int).values[0])*100).values[1], "attribute3":((df3.loc[i]["attribute3"].astype(int).diff()/df3.loc[i]["attribute3"].astype(int).values[0])*100).values[1], "Primary":"Change %"}, ignore_index=True)
        df4 = tempdf.append(df4)

df4.to_csv("dump1_dump2.csv", index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
Primary     attribute1    attribute2    attribute3
dump1_rowA  3992372839    3778338494    9180339101
dump2_rowA  8911849302    9018383910    8103293202
Change %       123.222       138.687      -11.7321
dump1_rowB  8291392010    3739203044    2840493019
dump2_rowB  7310393021    8301940301    7209301030
Change %      -11.8315       122.024       153.805
```

Hope this solves your problem, if not kindly let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one small additional requirement. It would be really helpful if you help me on the same! Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Updated the same. Hope this will work. If it does kindly upvote the post, this will keep me motivated.

Comment: Thanks again for enhancing this! I have found a couple of bugs here.. Please have a look in this [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18HYOoRqBtjI1ytkKVQCcWusuhgaruinP/view?usp=sharing) for the details.